# XNA -- Setting Position for an Array of Sprites per Index

Tags: xna, sprite

I'm having a problem setting the position and subsequently drawing individual elements from within an array of sprites. I have no issue with standalone sprites, but I'm getting tripped up on the array.

Simple example to illustrate the problem, real code is proper, but same concept --

```
myVar[0]=myImg;
myVar[0].Position.X=300;
myVar[0].Position.Y=300;
myVar[1]=myImg;
myVar[1].Position.X=400;
myVar[1].Position.Y=400;
```

If I go to now draw these, only myVar[1] @ 400 is painted because myVar[0] has also taken the same position. This is only a problem when the same image is used in multiple elements. Essentially I am drawing a 20x20 grid array using only 5 different tile images, so naturally there will be some re-used.

Is Sprite array capable of having a per index position...? Can I get around this in some way?

I was able to sidestep this earlier on by looping through and setting position then subsequently drawing per index, but now I need to take calculations in another function based on position, and my position is the same for all elements

Cheers & thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are referencing one object multiple times.

myVar[0] and myVar[1] are pointing to the same memory location. What you most likely want to do is create a new Sprite for every entry.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myVar.length; i++) {
  myVar[i] = new Sprite(<your img>);//This will ensure you have a different 
                                    //memory location for each Sprite object 
                                    //but keep the same image.
}
```

Then you can modify the positions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. XNA specific solution involved using an array of Strings which contained filenames and I'm loading new Sprites per myVar index using the sprite with a filename from a random indice from the string array. Working perfectly now. :)